# How to append an image from URL to a FormData - Javascript

Tags: javascript, form-data

This is my little javascript code:

```
<script>

var formData = new FormData();

URL = "view.php?fetchImageById=1";

formData.append("imageFile", ....);

formData.append("author","user");
formData.append("description","image");

x=new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open("POST","upload.php",true);
x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
x.setRequestHeader("Content-Length",formData.length);
x.send(formData);
</script>
```

I don't know how to append the URL to the formData.

Comment: The same way you append everything else… (although I suspect that you don't actually mean "append the URL to the formData").

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could perform two `XMLHttpRequest()`s; first `GET` request image as a `Blob` first by setting `responseType` to `"blob"`; then append `Blob` response to `FormData` at `POST`

```
var formData = new FormData();   
URL = "view.php?fetchImageById=1";    
var x;

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.responseType = "blob";
request.onload = function() {
  formData.append("imageFile", request.response);
  formData.append("author","user");
  formData.append("description","image");
  x = new XMLHttpRequest();
  x.open("POST","upload.php",true);
  x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
  x.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", formData.length);
  x.send(formData);
}
request.open("GET", URL);
request.send();
```

Comment: Make sure that don't use JSON.stringify to the body of the request