# Return PHP Variable to Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a page called *index.php*  where I have some forms where the user must input information.
On this page I have this JQuery functions.

```
 else if (result == 3)
 {

     jQuery.get('sample.txt', function(data) {
         alert(data);
     });

 }
```

where the file *sample.text* its shown on an alert.

But, I have a page called *download.php*. When the user click on "submit" at page "index.php" , its send to the page "download.php", the values sent using Ajax POST.

```
var formData = new FormData($('#form_principal')[0]);
     $("#loading").show();

    setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({url: "/tkclientespdo/etiquetaslog/000/0000/download.php",
                  type: "post",

                  data: formData,
                  cache: false,
                  async:true,
                  contentType: false,
                   processData: false,
                  success: function(result)
```

on page "download.php" i have this variable :

```
$horaenvio = date("dmYGis");
```

after this variable i have a code :

```
echo 3;
```

that return the function at index.php . 
but i wanna change 'sample.txt" for the variable "$horaenvio".

someone could help.

Comment: If all you seem to be doing with ajax and php is formatting a date, why not just do it in javascript?

Comment: `file_put_contents('path/to/sample.txt', $horaenvio);`?

Comment: You mean `$.get('<?=$horaenvio ?>', function(data) {`

Comment: You could return a json string. `<?php header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); echo json_encode(3);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` and `storage` event or `SharedWorker` to store the value `data` at `index.php`, and get the value at `download.php`, then `.append()` `data` to the `FormData` object, then `echo` the proper `POST` value.

Comment: could u made a example ?

Comment: @Kamikaz0r Is `download.php` expected to be visited after `.index.php`?

Comment: @Kamikaz0r See [Can we refer to JavaScript variables across webpages in a browser session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36146595/can-we-refer-to-javascript-variables-across-webpages-in-a-browser-session/), [JavaScript Session storage variable on another page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38034647/), [Can the mechanism that loads the worker in Shared Web Workers be modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38938039/), [How to append an image from URL to a FormData - Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37241882/)